# How to display an image generated dynamically by javascript in jsf page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, highcharts

Using JSF and PrimeFaces I try to use java script external library (Highcharts) in order to display an image generated dynamically. Data used by the image is loaded from database. Image should be refreshed every n seconds.

In JSF I know that I can run java script function by

> < h:outputScript name="js/volatilityChart.js">

but I have to somehow put parameters in order to appropriately display this function. I know there is possibility of calling execute() from RequestContext but I have no idea how to display an image generated in such a way. If knew I could probably use p:poll in order to refreshing it. I've searched the web but couldn't find proper solution. 
Any advice will be appreciated.

Edited:

As followed BalusC suggestion and after some digging I managed to create something that suits me (simply speaking accessing bean fields and methods inside javascript code within xhtml). In XHTML I put:

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
        $(function () {
            $('#container_portfolio').highcharts('StockChart', {
                chart: {
                    alignTicks: false
                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
                    selected: 1
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },

                    series: [{
                        type: 'column',
                        name: 'Volatility',
                        data: #{statisticsView.getStatistic()},
                        dataGrouping: {
                            units: [[
                                'week', // unit name
                                [1] // allowed multiples
                            ], [
                                'month',
                                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                            ]]
                        }
                    }]
                });
            });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Above function works and gives what I expected. However, I would like to insert many similar calls. Is it somehow possible to extract them to separate files? It would dramatically increase manageability of the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not different from when you'd do it in plain HTML. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator (you probably already know, JavaScript is as being a client side language just part of that HTML). You just have to write JSF code accordingly so that it generates exactly the desired HTML. So, if you can figure out how the generated HTML should look like, and you don't know how to write JSF as such that it generates exactly that HTML, then just ask here, along with the desired HTML output so that we have something to start with.

Comment: Generally, this line you load file, but you need to call javascript function anywhere.